# Помогите исправить кнопку воспроизведения аудио в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Проблема в том, что в игре есть кнопка вкл и выкл звука. Я цепляю этот скрипт на кнопку, но при нажатие звук не выключается. В чем может быть проблема?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class UI_MainPanel : MonoBehaviour {

    public Sprite spriteSoundOn, spriteSoundOff, spriteVibrateOn, spriteVibrateOff;

    public Button buttonSound, buttonVibrate;

    public Text textCoins;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void OnEnable () {
        UpdateStates ();
        UpdateCoins ();
    }

    void UpdateCoins()
    {
        textCoins.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("Coins",100).ToString();
    }

    void UpdateStates()
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("isSoundOn", 1) == 1)
            buttonSound.image.sprite = spriteSoundOn;
        else
            buttonSound.image.sprite = spriteSoundOff;

        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("isVibrationOn", 1) == 1)
            buttonVibrate.image.sprite = spriteVibrateOn;
        else
            buttonVibrate.image.sprite = spriteVibrateOff;
    }

    public void ButtonToggleSound()
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("isSoundOn", 1) == 1)
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("isSoundOn", 0);
        else
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("isSoundOn", 1);

        UpdateStates ();
        SoundManager.Instance.PlayButtonTapSound ();
    }


    public void ButtonToggleVibration()
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("isVibrationOn", 1) == 1)
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("isVibrationOn", 0);
        else
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("isVibrationOn", 1);

        UpdateStates ();
        SoundManager.Instance.PlayButtonTapSound ();
    }

    public void ButtonSkins()
    {
        GUIManager.Instance.OpenPanel (4);
        SoundManager.Instance.PlayButtonTapSound ();
    }

    public void ButtonPlay()
    {
        GUIManager.Instance.OpenPanel (1,true);
        GameManager.Instance.ResumeGame ();
        SoundManager.Instance.PlayButtonTapSound ();

    }

    public void ButtonLeaderboard()
    {
        GUIManager.Instance.ButtonLeaderboard ();
        SoundManager.Instance.PlayButtonTapSound ();
    }

    public void ButtonRate()
    {
        GUIManager.Instance.ButtonRate ();
        SoundManager.Instance.PlayButtonTapSound ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Все, что делает ваша кнопка по звуку - сохраняет значение в PlayerPrefs и меняет спрайт. Со звуком, судя по данному коду, она никак не взаимодействует.

Comment: А не подскажите, пожалуйста, как добавить вкл и выкл звука в этот скрипт?

Comment: Я не знаю, как у вас в игре звук устроен, без какого-либо кода помочь нереально

Comment: Полагаю, на каком-то из объектов у вас есть Audio Listener. Вот его через GetComponent делайте неактивным.